# PuLP Optimization Troubleshooting

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, constraints

I'm currently working on a project to optimize part production by employee based on their part production efficiency.  I've currently compiled all the information from SQL, and brought them into a dataframe to be explored.  I'm also taking user inputs from production manager to get the part no and qty of parts needed.  The goal is to change the QtyProduced column to the optimized amount (integer would be ideal) using the Pulp package.  The TimeUsed column will be automatically updated as the QtyProduced is updated.  I'm using the average TimeUsed as the objective to minimize, and making sure every employee stays under the Available Time constraint and each part qty is met.

I believe this is set up wrong, but not sure where it gets hung up.  When I enter a single part and qty of a small integer like 5, the solver still gives 'Linear relaxation infeasible'.

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.9.0 
Build Date: Feb 12 2015 

At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 27 COLUMNS
At line 29 RHS
At line 52 BOUNDS
At line 54 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 22 rows, 1 columns and 0 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Empty problem - 22 rows, 1 columns and 0 elements
Empty problem - 22 rows, 1 columns and 0 elements
Primal infeasible - objective value 0
PrimalInfeasible objective 0 - 0 iterations time 0.002

Result - Linear relaxation infeasible

Enumerated nodes:           0
Total iterations:           0
Time (CPU seconds):         0.00
Time (Wallclock Seconds):   0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is some example code and output that I'm working with:

```
Enter number of different parts: 3
Enter Part Number : 23496434-LH
Enter Qty of Part Number : 5
Enter Part Number : 84312875-LH-D
Enter Qty of Part Number : 50
Enter Part Number : 84729097-LH-D
Enter Qty of Part Number : 60

      PartNo      QtyProduced QtyNeeded
0    23496434-LH       0           5   
1  84312875-LH-D       0          50   
2  84729097-LH-D       0          60   

            EmplName           TimeUsed  AvailableTime
0          Employee A             0.0        530.0    
1          Employee B             0.0        530.0    
2          Employee C             0.0        530.0    
3          Employee D             0.0        530.0    
4          Employee E             0.0        530.0    
5          Employee F             0.0        530.0    
6          Employee G             0.0        530.0    
7          Employee H             0.0        530.0    
8          Employee I             0.0        530.0    
9          Employee J             0.0        530.0    

Total number of decision variables: 30
       PartNo     QtyNeeded  CycleTime           EmplName           UpdatedJobEff  QtyProduced  TimeUsed
0     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee A             1.083794          0        0.0  
1     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee B             1.310655          0        0.0  
2     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee C             0.400000          0        0.0  
3     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee D             0.400000          0        0.0  
4     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee E             1.244152          0        0.0  
5     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee F             0.400000          0        0.0  
6     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee G             0.400000          0        0.0  
7     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee H             0.400000          0        0.0  
8     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee I             0.400000          0        0.0  
9     23496434-LH      5       25.0             Employee J             0.400000          0        0.0  
10  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee A             0.400000          0        0.0  
11  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee B             1.171081          0        0.0  
12  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee C             0.400000          0        0.0  
13  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee D             0.400000          0        0.0  
14  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee E             1.018995          0        0.0  
15  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee F             0.400000          0        0.0  
16  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee G             0.400000          0        0.0  
17  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee H             0.720496          0        0.0  
18  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee I             0.617332          0        0.0  
19  84312875-LH-D     50       30.0             Employee J             0.400000          0        0.0  
20  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee A             0.400000          0        0.0  
21  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee B             0.400000          0        0.0  
22  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee C             1.098460          0        0.0  
23  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee D             0.400000          0        0.0  
24  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee E             0.553506          0        0.0  
25  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee F             0.400000          0        0.0  
26  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee G             0.400000          0        0.0  
27  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee H             0.400000          0        0.0  
28  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee I             0.400000          0        0.0  
29  84729097-LH-D     60       15.0             Employee J             0.400000          0        0.0
```

```
# User Input Part Number, Qty, and pull description and CycleTime for Each #

total_parts = int(input("Enter number of different parts: "))
partno = []
quantity = []
for i in range(total_parts):
    pn = input("Enter Part Number : ").strip()
    qty = input("Enter Qty of Part Number : ")
    partno.append(pn)
    quantity.append(qty)
b = {'PartNo': partno, 'QtyNeeded': quantity}
DailyDemand = pd.DataFrame(b)

c = pd.merge(DailyDemand, part_number_breakdown)
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
#print(DailyDemand)

# Merging Efficiencies with Parts Entered #

combined_df = pd.merge(c, production_df, on='PartNo', how='left')
combined_df['QtyProduced'] = 0
combined_df['TimeUsed'] = (combined_df.CycleTime * combined_df.QtyProduced)/combined_df.UpdatedJobEff
#print(combined_df)

# Counting Employees #

n = len(pd.unique(combined_df['EmplName']))
#print("")
#print("Number of Employees : ", n)
UniqueEmpl = pd.DataFrame(pd.unique(combined_df['EmplName']))


# Constraint Dataframes #

total_produced = combined_df.groupby('PartNo')['QtyProduced'].sum().reset_index()
total_produced = pd.merge(total_produced, DailyDemand)
total_empl_time = combined_df.groupby('EmplName')['TimeUsed'].sum().reset_index()
total_empl_time['AvailableTime'] = 530.0

print("")
print(total_produced)
print("")
print(total_empl_time)

# Importing PulP and Checking Decision Variables #

import pulp

decision_variables = []
for rownum, row in combined_df.iterrows():
    variablestr = str('x' + str(rownum))
    variable = pulp.LpVariable(str(variablestr), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Integer')
    decision_variables.append(variable)
print("")
print("Total number of decision variables: " + str(len(decision_variables)))

# Define Optimize Function and Constraints#

prob = pulp.LpProblem('AverageTotalTime', pulp.LpMinimize)

prob += sum(combined_df['TimeUsed'])/n, "obj"

for index, row in total_empl_time.iterrows():
    prob += pulp.LpConstraint(row['TimeUsed'] <= row['AvailableTime'])
    prob += pulp.LpConstraint(row['TimeUsed'] >= 0)

for index, row in total_produced.iterrows():
    prob += pulp.LpConstraint(row['QtyProduced'] == row['QtyNeeded'])
    prob += pulp.LpConstraint(row['QtyProduced'] >= 0)

########################################################################################################################

prob.solve()
pulp.LpStatus[prob.status]
```

Comment: it’s much easier to work with a matrix then a data frame, also in your loops you aren’t using the loop variables, you probably want to use the row variable instead

Comment: then you set up the optimization problem incorrectly, please update the post with the modified code

Comment: I'm expecting the solver to change the QtyProduced Column which minimizes the AvgTotalTime and meets all part QtyNeeded constraints

Comment: but you're not updating those variables, you are simply updating the `prob` variable. I will try to take a look shortly but I am more familiar with `google-or-tools` and not `PULP`

Comment: I'm trying to update the QtyProduced variable indirectly through TimeUsed, which ties the QtyProduced, ExpectedTime, and employee part efficiency together.  Its calculated as (QtyProduced * ExpectedTime)/Efficiency

Comment: No offense, but this is a total mess.  Your pulp problem is not constructed properly as you are using df components in it, not variables, among many other problems.  My suggestion:  Get rid of pandas in this project (it is just adding to the confusion), and try a couple of pulp models on the side with some hard coded data from dictionaries (like only 3 employees and products) until you get that working confidently and then scale up slowly.  You need to invest some time looking at pulp problems and models and work on some small examples.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm not very experienced in python.  So like gold_cy suggested, would you have the inputs go into a numpy array? Would you advise a different optimization package?

Comment: No `numpy` and no `pandas`.  Both are unnecessary and confusing when setting up an optimization model.  `pulp` is just fine.  Using python dictionaries will most likely be your best option.  search for a couple tutorials on how to set up models.  You are trying to wrestle a big gorilla here as a beginner, but if you invest a little time working with some of the tutorials, you will find the model above is pretty straightforward after you get the construction right.